# Lucene query fails with mixed MUST/MUST_NOT

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

Given a document with this text, indexed in a field named Content:

```
The dish ran away with the spoon.
```

The following query fails to match that document:

```
+Content:dish +(-Content:xyz)   <-- no results!
```

I want the query to be treated as **must include "dish", must not include "xyz"**. It's the "must not" part that is failing.

I know the +- combination looks funny but syntactically it should be correct, especially considering that the following variations all work:

```
+Content:dish +(-Content:xyz +Content:spoon)   <-- this works
+Content:dish -Content:xyz                     <-- this works
```

So why doesn't `+(-Content:xyz)` work? Is that by design, or a bug, or am I just missing something? I'm using Lucene.Net but I assume regular Lucene behaves the same.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Lucene doesn't start with a full view of everything, like a SQL database.  Lucene starts with no documents matched, and finds things based on the clauses searched on.  This is why:

```
-Content:xyz
```

On it's own doesn't really work.  It knows not to bring in content:xyz, but hasn't been given any documents to match.  The same is true of your query, because it's placed in a subquery.

`-Content:xyz` is evaluated first, which gets no docs on it's own.  So then you have, effectively

```
+Content:dish +(no documents)
```

It's useful to think of `-` as an `AND NOT` rather than simply a `NOT` (though don't take that to imply the +/- and AND/OR/NOT syntax necessarily map to each other directly).

If you want to be able to execute a lonely negative query like that, you need to bring in all documents first.  The [MatchAllDocsQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/MatchAllDocsQuery.html) is the best way to accomplish that, something like:

```
BooleanQuery query = new BooleanQuery();
query.add(new BooleanClause(new MatchAllDocsQuery(), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD));
query.add(new BooleanClause(new TermQuery(new Term("Content","xyz")), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST_NOT));
```

Would be the equivalent of a SQL style query with only a negation for a WHERE clause.

Of course, this isn't really necessary in the case you've listed since:

```
+Content:dish -Content:xyz
```

Is perfectly adequate.

Comment: Makes sense to me now. Thanks!

Comment: FYI the string representation of a MatchAllDocsQuery is `*:*`. My example above should be changed to the following for it to work: `+Content:dish +(+*:* -Content:xyz)`

Comment: @Keith Well, no, it **should** be changed to the equivalent: `Content:dish -Content:xyz`, but, yes, that would work (slowly).  Couldn't recall what the support for `*:*` was like (whether it was just in Solr, which versions supported it, whether it is supported by the .Net impl).

Comment: that suggestion is not correct:
 "Lucene doesn't start with a full view of everything, like a SQL database. "
You can customize document collector, develop own - then it easelly will show everythnig like in table.
Plus:  i prefer to don't construct such "complex queries" is betther to construct few simple and use bitmap (standard bit logic to combine 0 and 1). it is more easy to undestand and much faster forks