# How to negate a solr query with the surround query parser

Tags: solr, lucene, surround, booleanquery

Is there a way to negate a solr surround query? I'm using it in a fq field, if that gives me more options for negating the results.

```
fq={!surround}fieldName:2w(foo,bar)
```

I normally negate a filter by prepending '-', e.g.,

```
fq=-fieldName:baz
```

But when you do this with the surround query you get an error:

```
fq=-{!surround}fieldName:2w(foo,bar)

org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: org.apache.lucene.queryparser.surround.parser.ParseException: Encountered "<EOF>" at line 1, column 24.
Was expecting one of:
    <OR> ...
    <AND> ...
    <NOT> ...
    <W> ...
    <N> ...
    ")" ...
    "," ...
    "^" ...
```

Okay, so maybe '-' is not allowed and you can't have a lonely NOT. This works:

```
q={!surround}AND(fieldName:2w(foo,bar),otherField:baz)
```

but this fails

```
q={!surround}AND(NOT(fieldName:2w(foo,bar)),otherField:baz)

org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: org.apache.lucene.queryparser.surround.parser.ParseException: Encountered " <NOT> "NOT "" at line 1, column 4.
Was expecting one of:
    <OR> ...
    <AND> ...
    <W> ...
    <N> ...
    "(" ...
    <TRUNCQUOTED> ...
    <QUOTED> ...
    <SUFFIXTERM> ...
    <TRUNCTERM> ...
    <TERM> ...
```

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the "Was expecting one of" bit, Surround doesn't support +/- syntax, but it does have `NOT`:

```
NOT(fieldName:baz)
```

[Careful of that lonely NOT, though.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16091066/1628375)

Answer (score 0):

As of 8.2 (and unlikely to be fixed by 8.3) the syntax of NOT is incorrectly documented as "unary" it is in fact binary and requires a preceding term, so it likes

```
foo NOT bar
```

to find things with foo and not bar, so your query would be

```
{!surround}fieldName:2w(foo,bar) NOT (otherField:baz)
```

The last parenthesis around the field appear to be required, for no good reason. I did test that Solr will accept this query. I didn't have data handy to verify that it gives exactly the result you hoped for.