# Best way to index boolean values. Skip false and use MUST_NOT be true?

Tags: c#, indexing, lucene, lucene.net

I am using `Lucene.Net` for my indexing.

For certain fields I have a `true`/`false` value, that is passed to a analyzer `ANALYZED`.

My questions is simple, is it better to skip the value `false` and pass a empty value to the indexer and perform a search for `'false'` using `BooleanQuery` and search using `Occur.MUST_NOT = true` , or is it better to index it and search for `Occur.MUST = false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely keep the "false" values in the index.

Queries like: `-myBool:true` are [problematic in Lucene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089831/lucene-query-fails-with-mixed-must-must-not/16091066#16091066), and may force you into workarounds with a [`MatchAllDocsQuery`](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/d5/d10/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_search_1_1_match_all_docs_query.html), which is both awkward and a performance killer.

Any savings you would get on space from eliminating them would likely be trivial, *especially* if the field in question is index-only (not stored).