# Elasticsearch lucene query

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I am searching on an element called package, which has the field pkg_scope.

When I add the following string to my query I get 200 results:

```
AND ( pkg_scope:'Scope Undefined')
```

When I add the following string instead, I get one result:

```
AND ( NOT pkg_scope:'Top File')
```

The one result has a scope 'Scope Undefined'. I think it is reasonable to expect that the second query results would contain the results of the first one. Am I missing something ?

This is the complete query:

```
 query: *:* AND rectype:'Package' AND isPublic:"Yes" AND ( NOT pkg_scope:'Top File'  )
```

I am using ES 1.7.1

Comment: Why would you expect a more restrictive query (one with more required `AND` clauses) would have *more* results?  And why are you starting your query with a `*:*`?  The query `*:* AND field:term` gets exactly the same results as `field:term`, only slower (unless elasticsearch is smart enough to optimize away the `*:*`, which it might be).

Comment: Sorry maybe my wording is not correct. The two first queries are interchanged at the end of the last query.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now.  Thanks for clarifying.  I believe the problem you are running into is this one:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089831/lucene-query-fails-with-mixed-must-must-not/16091066#16091066   I'm a bit confused, though, as to why you are getting any results at all in that case.

Comment: By the way, for this and other problems [I kinda hate lucene's and/or/not syntax](https://lucidworks.com/blog/why-not-and-or-and-not/).  +/- syntax is much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the quotes around the string. For more than one words, double quotes need to be used. 
So  `NOT pkg_scope:'Top File'` need to be changed to  `NOT pkg_scope:"Top File"`