# Solr query conundrum

Tags: linq, solr, lucene, sitecore, sitecore8

I've recently swapped from using Lucene for Sitecore to Solr.

For the most part it has been smooth, but the way I was writing some queries (using Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq) abstraction now don't seem to be compatible.

Specifically, I have a situation where I've got "global" content and "regional" content, like so:

- Home (000)

  - X
  - Y
  - Z
- Regions (ID: 111)

  - Region 1 (ID: 221)

    - A
    - B
  - Region 2 (ID: 222)

    - D

My code worked on Lucene, but now doesn't on Solr. It should find all "global" and a single region's content, excluding all other region's content. So as an example, if the user's current region was Region 1, I'd want the query to return content X, Y, Z, A, B.

Sitecore's Item Crawler has a field for each item in the index called "_path" which is a multivalued string field of IDs, so as an example, Region 1's _path field value would be [000, 111, 221 ].

When I write this using the Linq abstraction it comes out as below which doesn't return results.

`-_path:(111) OR _path:(221)`

But _path:(111) does return result. *Mind blown*.

When I use the Solr interface and wrap each side of the OR in extra brackets like below (which I'd consider redundant) it works! *Mind blown v2*.

`(-_path:(111)) OR (_path:(221))`

Firstly, what's the difference between those queries?

Secondly, my real problem is I can't add these extra brackets as I'm working in an abstraction Linq so the brackets will be "optimized" out.

Any advice would be awesome! Cheers.

Comment: Can you post your code which is used to generate the query?

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is, lucene's negative queries don't work like you think they do.  They *only* remove results from what has been found.  `-_path:111` doesn't find all documents which aren't in 111, it doesn't find *anything at all*.  It only removes results.  So you are finding all results with path "221", then removing any that also have path "111", which from your heirarchy, I assume is all of them.  [See my answer here for a bit more on that topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089831/lucene-query-fails-with-mixed-must-must-not/16091066#16091066).

The OR makes it seem like it ought to work, but really `-_path:(111) OR _path:(221)` is the same as `-_path:(111) _path:(221)`.  The moral here is:  [Don't use Lucene's AND/OR/NOT syntax](https://lucidworks.com/blog/why-not-and-or-and-not/), if you can help it.  Use +/-.  +/- syntax actually expresses how the query operates, AND/OR/NOT doesn't.  It attempts to shoehorn it into a different, SQL-like retrieval model and leads to some unexpected behavior like this.

So, what about:  `(-_path:(111)) OR (_path:(221))`

Well, first, does it actually work?  Or does it just get some results?

- If it just gets some results, but just seems to get the same results as `_path:221`:  The reason is `-_path:111` gets no results, so your query is, in practice, something like: `(nothing) OR (_path:221)`, which is equivalent to `_path:221`
- If it really does get the results you expect (I'm guessing it probably does):  Something is translating your query into something like:  `(*:* -_path:111) (_path:221)`.  Solr does have some logic along these lines, though I'm not quite sure in this case.  Essentially, it puts a match-all in front of any lonely negative queries it finds, allowing them to do what you were expecting.  If the implicit `*:*` makes you nervous about performance, well, it should.  But lucene is an inverted index, it does well with finding matches on a term quickly.  Getting everything that *doesn't* match goes against the grain of that retrieval model, and will pretty much have to do a full scan of the index.

Comment: Sorry for such a late reply. I think I see what you mean, but my programmer's brain is hindering me.

In the end, I added an always true expression (ie. `_path:(000)`) as an AND with the `-_path:(111)` so that the final query became: `(-_path:111 AND _path:000) OR _path:221` and it returned what I needed. 

Still doesn't explain why this became an issue after transitioning to Solr.

Comment: I'll try and do some more digging to prove your answer before I mark it as correct. Thanks for your help!